# Sticky sidebar is behaving erratically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**DEMO:** [**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLRoGE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLRoGE)

My page with sticky sidebar written in jQuery/Bootstrap is working exactly how I want it however, as I scroll, the sidebar isn't smooth and behaves erratically. It jerks as the user scrolls.

The functionality is otherwise just the way I want it which stops when the content of the sidebar reaches its' bottom.

HTML:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.fn.stickyTopBottom = function() {
    var options = {
      container: jQuery('#stickymain'),
      top_offset: 0,
      bottom_offset: 0
    };
    console.log(options);
    let jQueryel = jQuery(this)

    let container_top = options.container.offset().top
    let element_top = jQueryel.offset().top

    let viewport_height = jQuery(window).height()
    jQuery(window).on('resize', function() {
      viewport_height = jQuery(window).height()
    });
    let current_translate = 0
    let last_viewport_top = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      var viewport_top = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
      let viewport_bottom = viewport_top + viewport_height
      let effective_viewport_top = viewport_top + options.top_offset
      let effective_viewport_bottom = viewport_bottom - options.bottom_offset


      let element_height = jQueryel.height()

      let is_scrolling_up = viewport_top < last_viewport_top
      let element_fits_in_viewport = element_height < viewport_height

      let new_translation = null
      if (is_scrolling_up) {
        if (effective_viewport_top < container_top)
          new_translation = 0
        else if (effective_viewport_top < element_top + current_translate)
          new_translation = effective_viewport_top - element_top
      } else if (element_fits_in_viewport) {
        if (effective_viewport_top > element_top + current_translate)
          new_translation = effective_viewport_top - element_top

      } else {
        let container_bottom = container_top + options.container.height()
        if (effective_viewport_bottom > container_bottom)
          new_translation = container_bottom - (element_top + element_height)
        else if (effective_viewport_bottom > element_top + element_height + current_translate)
          new_translation = effective_viewport_bottom - (element_top + element_height)
      }
      if (new_translation != null) {
        current_translate = new_translation;
        console.log('i am here at css');

        jQueryel.css('transform', ('translate(0, ' + current_translate + 'px)'));
      }
      last_viewport_top = viewport_top
    });
  }
  jQuery('#stickyside').stickyTopBottom();
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.col-xs-8 {
  background: lightgray;
}
.main {
  min-height: 1200px;
}
#stickyside {
  position: absolute;
}
#footer {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="container" id="stickymain">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="main">
        <p>This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the
          main content.This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content.
          This is the main content.</p>
        <p>This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the
          main content.This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content.
          This is the main content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="stickyside">
        <p class="red">See how this sidebar flickers as you scroll? I want to fix this.</p>
        <p>This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling.This
          is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling.
          This is the end where it stops scrolling. This is the end where it stops scrolling.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

What do I do top stop this jerking effect during scrolling?

Comment: It's worth noting that it seems fine in Chrome, but is erratic in Firefox.

Comment: Try scrolling it a little slow or multiple times. Sometimes it scrolls smoothly. It is erratic in my Chrome (Mac). So is in Firefox and Safari :(

Comment: Do you have some opposition to setting the `#stickyside` element to a fixed positioning when the scroll distance has reached so far down? It seems that would be a better way then modifying the position with every scroll event.

Comment: How do I detect and fix the position?

Answer (score 0):

From what I  can tell, this is because the content of the sidebar has to be redrawn every time the content 'scrolls'. Think of it like a poor frame-rate on a video game.

You could probably fix this issue, by allowing it to scroll normally, and upon the event that you use to stop it from scrolling, use the javascript function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

```
document.getElementById(/*Element id*/).style
```

to change the property style from absolute to fixed.